# How to make two sound buttons play at once

Tags: button

I tried doing this with javascript and howler.js, but have come up against the wall of "javascript is single thread".

My task at the moment is to create a piano that can play more than one note at a time (ie hit 2 or 3 keys and you hear all those keys sounds). With my current javascript model, hitting 2 keys at once does nothing at all (although hitting any single key works).

So I may need to go somewhere other than javascript. I'm open to any suggestions. (note: I'm not a great coder -- I've learned html, css and now some javascript, and can work in flash pro a bit as well, but am willing to learn new things, but not able to spend too much time on it).

(I also suspect some pianos are doing something else with javascript to pseudo-play 2 notes at once. Here's Virtual Piano, which I don't know if it does but I suspect uses javascript, and it plays 2 notes http://virtualpiano.net/

```
One helpful responded asked for the code I was working with, so here that is:

  <button id="Eb3btn"></button>
  <button id="Fbtn"></button>

  <script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/javascript/howler.js/howler.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      var Eb3 = new Howl({urls: ["<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/sounds/Eb3.mp3"]})
      document.getElementById('Eb3btn').onclick=function(){Eb3.play()};

      var F3 = new Howl({urls: ["<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/sounds/F3.mp3"]})
      document.getElementById('Fbtn').onclick=function(){F3.play()};
  </script>
```

Comment: Show some code. How are you currently playing sounds? It's true that JS is single thread (well, sort of -- we have 'webworkers' now) but that doesn't mean that playing a sound has to be blocking.

Comment: Have a look at the Web Audio API https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API, it's designed specially for that kind of problems. I've been able to design a step sequencer and a 4 oscillators multi-voice synthethizer natively in Javascript without too much of a hassle

Comment: Hi Maxime Piraux, yes, I think the howler.js is based on Web Audio API, which I've been seeing quite a bit of. Congratulations on your sequencer. I'd like to try one of those, too. Is it live online?